# How do I deal with when a user enters a taken coordinate in tic-tac-toe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, tic-tac-toe

I am writing a tic-tac toe program. Right now the user can override a taken square. Also, when the user enters a coordinate not on the board, it skips that persons turn. I would like to make my program say something like "the coordinate you have entered has already been taken or is invalid" when the user enters a taken coordinate or a coordinate not on the board. The program would then need to give the user another chance to enter his/her coordinate. Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
class Game

        def initialize
                @board=Array.new
                @board[1]="  1   2   3\n" + "1  __|"
                @board[2]="__"
                @board[3]="|__"
                @board[4]="\n2  __|"
                @board[5]="__"
                @board[6]="|__"
                @board[7]="\n3    |"
                @board[8]="  "
                @board[9]="|  "
                @turn="x"
                @win_status = false
        end

        def turn
                @turn
        end

        def show_board
                @board.each do |i|
                        print i
                end
                puts ""
        end

        def set_turn #switches turns
        if @turn == "x"
                @turn = "o"
        else @turn == "o"
                @turn = "x"
        end
        end

        def make_move
                puts "Enter x coordinate"
                x=gets.to_i
                puts "Enter y coordinate"
                y=gets.to_i
@board[1]="1  _"+@turn+"|"   if y==1 && x==1
@board[2]="_"+@turn    if y==2 && x==1
@board[3]="|_"+@turn   if y==3 && x==1
@board[4]="\n_"+@turn+"|" if y==1 && x==2
@board[5]="_"+@turn    if y==2 && x==2
@board[6]="|_"+@turn   if y==3 && x==2
@board[7]="\n "+@turn+"|" if y==1 && x==3
@board[8]=" "+@turn    if y==2 && x==3
@board[9]="|"+@turn+" \n"    if y==3 && x==3
        end
 def win_combo
                return [[@board[1][1] + @board[2][1] + @board[3][2]], [@board[4][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[6][2]], [@board[7][1] + @board[8][1] + @board[9][1]],[@board[1][1] + @board[4][2] + @board[7][1]], [@board[2][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[8][1]], [@board[3][2] + @board[6][2] + @board[9][1]], [@board[1][1] + @board[5][1] + @board[9][1]], [@board[3][2] + @board[5][1] + @board[7][1]]]
        end

        def check_win
                #if some row or column or diagonal is "xxx" or "ooo" then set @win_status = true
                self.win_combo.each do |arr|
                        str = arr.join
                        if str == "xxx" or str == "ooo"
                                return true
                        end
                end
                return false
        end
end


g = Game.new
while g.check_win != true
        g.show_board
        g.set_turn
        g.make_move
end
puts "won"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing each of these lines that you have

```
@board[1]="1  _"+@turn+"|"   if y==1 && x==1
```

to:

```
if y==1 && x==1 && @board[1].eql?("  1  2  3\n" + "1 _|")
  @board[1] = "1 _" +@turn + "|"
```

and use elsif for @board[2-9]. The @board[1].eql?() part is what you initialized those values to. At the end of all that put this line:

```
else
  make_move
end
```

Now it will only let you change the value of @board[x] if it hasn't been changed already. And if none of the conditions are satisfied to change that value, it will run the make_move method again. The final code should look something like this

```
if y==1 && x==1 && @board[1].eql?("  1  2  3\n" + "1 _|")
  @board[1] = "1 _" +@turn + "|" 
elsif y==2 && x==1 && ...
  ...
else
  make_move
end
```